# jquery .click form submit not working in ie8 or below-

Tags: javascript, jquery

im having trouble with a form submit script im using with javascript and jquery- its a form i have loaded into a facebook tab which when submit should pass a variable to another tab.

it works in **ie9**, **chrome**, **ff** and **safari** but client is stuck on **ie 7 and 8**. I dont know what the problem is- I have tried replace the button with a div and image incase **.click** wouldnt overwrite the submit function.

this should be a common problem with fix? or what am i doing thats completely wrong?

```
<script>
 $('document').ready( function(){
    $('#my_button').click(function (e) {
  //this.form.onsubmit();

      var_app = "444444";
      url = "http://www.facebook.com/tab/?sk=bladadasd&app_data=" + var_app;

      parent.window.location.replace(url);
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });
 });    
</script>

<form id="submit" method="POST" >
 <ul>
  <li><span>Photo code <sup class="required">*</sup></span><input id="barcode" name="barcode" type="text"/></li>
  <li><span>First name</span><input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text"/></li>
  <li><span>Last name</span><input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text"/></li>
  <li><span>Email address</span><input id="optional_email" name="optional_email" type="text"/></li>
 </ul>
 <a class="help">Need help?</a>  
 <input value="" type="submit" id="my_button" />  
</form>
```

edit the form bounces on to the correct page in normal browsers but in **ie8** it just submits upon itself going nowhere and displaying the same again

Comment: I think the problem is with preventDefault and return false. Other thing i can contribute is the use of the event .submit instead of click.

Comment: I suggest you to debug your code using Developers Tool inside IE7. Maybe you should access to `parent.window.location` property in a different way.

Comment: Try adding the `action` property to your form to have valid html. This can mess it up

Comment: Please be serious about formatting and punctuation if you want serious answer.

Comment: this issues seems to be with parent.window.location.replace(url); on a different machine ie7 is saying permission denied for this line

Answer (score 1):

If it is a submit button , then instead you should be working with `onsubmit` even on that form.

P.S. why is your `var_app` variable in global scope ?

Comment: var_app is in global score for quick testing/debugging. will try onsubmit :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the submit event instead of click event.

```
$('#my_button').submit(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();    
});
```

You are also missing an action for your form.

I wonder if you should also specify the [script type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html)

Answer (score 1):

Declare **var_app** & **url** variables.

```
  var var_app = "444444";
  var url = "http://www.facebook.com/tab/?sk=bladadasd&app_data=" + var_app;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error lay with the line

```
parent.window.location.replace(url);
```

internet explorer only allowed the following statement and would throw a permission error

```
parent.location.replace(url);
```

nothing to do with jquery or my form syntax :( only realised this when i ran the code on a different machine in ie7